# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken Rails 5 / Devise / Audited / PaperTrail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, acts-as-audited

**Background Details**

I am using **Devise** for authentication to login to a **Rails 5** application.

Whenever I bundle either the **Audited** or **Paper Trail** gem, when I attempt to #create a new session (via the sign in form - /users/sign_in), I receive the following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

**Environment Details**

**Ruby 2.3.1**

**Gems:**

- **rails** 5.0.2
- **devise** => 4.2.1
- **paper_trail** => 7.0.1

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create Rails 5 application
2. Add Devise gem
3. Add Audited or Paper Trail gem
4. Attempt to login

Comment: Do you have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in application_controller?

Comment: @whodini9 - Bingo.  That was the cause of the error.  I changed it to this:    

`protect_from_forgery prepend: true`  

And then things were happy.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As it turns out, [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) is quite revealing with regard to this error:

> For **Rails 5**, note that protect_from_forgery is no longer prepended to
>   the **before_action** chain, so if you have set authenticate_user before
>   **protect_from_forgery**, your request will result in "**Can't verify CSRF
>   token authenticity.**" **To resolve this, either change the order in which
>   you call them, or use protect_from_forgery prepend:   true**.

The fix was to change code in my application controller from this:

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

To this:

```
 protect_from_forgery prepend: true
```

This issue did not manifest itself until I attempted adding Audited or Paper Trail gems.

Comment: Worked for me, strangely enough, if you were still logged in, the problem doesn't appear, so it seemed intermittent.

Comment: @JohnLinux - I experienced the same thing.

I don't think it is intermittent though.  I think that Devise is sending you through a different call stack when you are logged in.

Comment: This was causing me a lot of confusion and frustration. Multiple other posts mention 'moving' it, but non specific the prepend. Thanks.

Comment: The proposed change is actually changing more. You probably want `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true`, but you end up with `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, prepend: true`  as :null_session is the default value of `with:`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on my development machine. Turns out I was setting

> Rails.application.config.session_store

for security purpose in production. And somehow in this code gets run on development mode. And I have to comment out this line and it works fine now.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_session', secure: true, same_site: :strict
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to try for anyone running into this is to add the following to your environment configuration file:

```
config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```

For me, production was working correctly but staging and development were not and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my project we have that problem and we can't to override *protect_from_forgery*. 
The solution founded is indicate the github of audited and worked for me.

Put this in gemfile:

```
gem "audited", github: "collectiveidea/audited"
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be an answer to the OP question?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, sorry I don't understand the OP question. My answer is to work without edit _protect_from_forgery_, because my project using a before_action callback to validate something before session create in devise. Sorry if is not clear in my answer.

Comment: @msfreire - are you suggesting that you can use 

 `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in your application controller if you use the github branch that you posted?

Comment: @aldefouw Yes. I dont need to change to `protect_from_forgery prepend: true` if you put the branch in gem file. I`m using rails 5.0.1, try that if you using rails 5+

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the  [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

> For Rails 5, note that `protect_from_forgery` is no longer prepended
>   to the before_action chain, so if you have set authenticate_user
>   before protect_from_forgery, your request will result in "Can't verify
>   CSRF token authenticity." To resolve this, either change the order in
>   which you call them, or use protect_from_forgery prepend: true.

I have used something like this and it works for me.

```
class WelcomeController < ::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate_model!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to manually go to my browser's settings and delete the cache.